# Weird JavaScript scoping behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Latey I've got some trouble with some weird javascript behavior. I want to do something like this:

```
var lang = null;

function getLang() {
    if (browserLanguageIsGerman) {
        lang = 'de';
    }
    else {
        lang = 'en';
    }
    // alert(lang) shows "de"

    $('#someID').load(someValidUrl, null, 
        function(response, status, xhr) {
            if(languageSettingsOnFacebookIsGerman) {
                lang = 'de';
            }
            else {
                lang = 'en';
            }
            // alert(lang) show "en"
    );
    // alert(lang) shows "de"
}
```

The first and the second alerts show the expacted value 1) "de" 2) "en". The third alert shows "de" but shouldn't it be "en"?!
Also the second alert pops up after the third alert.

Can someone please obvious bug in my mind? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using AJAX. Remember that AJAX is asynchronous!

Comment: The alerts are just adding more confusion because they can block the execution thread long enough for an ajax response to come back. Mixing ajax with alert debugging is a sure way to skew your understanding of what happens.

Comment: We should find out something because we get this same question several times every day.

Comment: @user1494845: Perhaps you should think about why you pass a function to `.load` at all. If the "de" alert would alert "en" instead, there is no reason for passing a function. You could use `.load`'s "return value" instead, or at least get rid of the whole function - but that's not possible due to the asynchronous concept, and hence you pass a function in the first place!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not an issue with scope. The [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method is asynchronous. The third `alert` is executed before the callback you pass to `load`. Move any code that depends on the result of that async call into the callback.

Alternatively, you can look into the [jQuery deferred objects API](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Note that if you were to use the deferred object API you would need to change you call to `load` to a call to [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), since `.load` returns an instance of jQuery, which doesn't implement the Promise interface.

Comment: ... or use [.then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) (or its equivalents) instead.

Comment: ... or use synchronous requests.
( set async to false: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ )

edit: don't do that.

Comment: @roman - Don't do that. It's going to be deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

Comment: @James, oh! I didn't see that

Comment: @raina77ow - Very true, but that would require a change to `$.get` or `$.ajax` since `.load()` returns an instance of jQuery, not of `jqXHR`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't. "load" doesn't wait info from your "someValidUrl" would be fetched. Instead, it postpones your internal function to be executed later, when the info would be available, and immediately returns without waiting. It is called "asyncronous".